# X index not found when trying to split in to train/ test sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a large dataframe `X` of floats and an array of target values `y` that I am trying to split in to train and test sets. However I am getting the following error:

`KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,\n            20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 38, 40, 41,\n            42],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"`

This is my code:

```py
split = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

I have tried converting the df index to int using:

`X = X.set_index(X.index.astype(int))`

but the error remains the same. I think there's something going on with the index of the df that means the code can't find the train/ test indexs, but I don't understand why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if X and y are numpy arrays not dataframe.
To use with pandas dataframe, change `X[train_index]` to `X.iloc[train_index]`

Comment: Ahh OK, that makes sense. Thank you!